# Combo gas/smoke/carbon monoxide detector

Tags: remote-control

Is anyone familiar with a battery operated or hardwired to 220-230V smoke, natural gas, and carbon monoxide detector?
Preferably one that can be monitored remotely (I want to connect it to Home Assistant).
I've found [this one](https://www.universalsecurity.com/combination-smoke-gas-alarms/hardwired-alarms-33/MICN109), but it works with 120V.
There are a bunch of remotely controlled ones on AliExpress, but are not all 3 combo.

Comment: How about using that one, with some voltage converter?